# Select the current element with the jquery in the react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm using react v16 and jquery v3.3.1, by default, `this` refers to its own class in the react and my problem is that how to select the current element using `$(this)` in a react component.

My codes are as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
const $ = require('jquery');    

export default class JunkListItem extends React.Component {

    constructor(props ) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            selected: false,
       };
       this.setIndex = this.setIndex.bind(this);
    }    

    setIndex() {

        if ($('.check-box > div').hasClass('scale-off')){

            $(this).removeClass('scale-off');

        }else{
            $(this).addClass('scale-off')
        }
   }


    render() {
        return(
            <li className="item">
                <div className="image-box">
                    <img className="no-select" src={`./images/${this.props.src}.${this.props.type}`} alt={this.props.itemName}/>                     
                </div>
                <div className="details">
                    <h3>{this.props.itemName}</h3>
                    <p>{this.props.itemDetails}</p>
                </div>

                <div className="check-box" onClick={this.setIndex}>
                    <div className='selected' />
                </div>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```

I have a number of checkboxs and i want when I click on each one just change the checkbox i chose. but `$(this)` refer to the current component instead of the current element.
Please guide me where the problem is?
Thanks.

Comment: Use refs instead of jquery to get hold of DOM element in react - https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not ideal to use jquery with React since jquery modifies the original DOM and react works on the principle of VirtualDOM for performance optimization, you can conditionally pass the class to the element like

```
export default class JunkListItem extends React.Component {

    constructor(props ) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            selected: false,
            classValue: ''
       };
       this.setIndex = this.setIndex.bind(this);
    }    

    setIndex() {

        if (!this.state.classValue !== ''){

            this.setState({classValue: 'scale-off'})

        }else{
            this.setState({classValue: ''})
        }
   }


    render() {
        return(
            <li className="item">
                <div className="image-box">
                    <img className="no-select" src={`./images/${this.props.src}.${this.props.type}`} alt={this.props.itemName}/>                     
                </div>
                <div className="details">
                    <h3>{this.props.itemName}</h3>
                    <p>{this.props.itemDetails}</p>
                </div>

                <div className="check-box" onClick={this.setIndex}>
                    <div className={`selected ${this.state.classValue} />
                </div>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind this context as below

```
onClick={this.setIndex.bind(this)}

 setIndex(e) {
  var currentTarget= $(e.currentTarget); //in case you wanted to use jQuery
 }
```

since functions are `event` event bound. So you always get event of current element.

Comment: `@Manoj` thanks, your answer is also correct, but the answer is principled to the `@Shubham Khatri`